# Updating the component unbinds the related event on it

Tags: reactjs

```js
var Field = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          Current: true
        };
      },
      ValChange: function(e) {
        alert(e);
      },
      render: function() {
          return ({
               this.state.Current ? <input className = "Searchtextbox"
               onChange = {this.ValChange} /> :  <span> nothing... </span>);
    }
});
```

when from other component the state changes to false the span screen comes.

When I turn back state of current to true and try to type something in the textbox field, the Valchange function doesn't get fired the second time.

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.

```
    var Field = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {
            Current: true
          };
        },
        ValChange: function(e) {
          alert(e);
        },
        render: function() {
            var returnIt = '';
            if (this.state.Current) returnIt = (
                <input className = "Searchtextbox" onChange = {this.ValChange} />
            );
            else returnIt = (<span> nothing... </span>);
            return returnIt;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I dont think this will going to solve my problem. Isn't It just another way of writing the code ?